# Find the density and distribution of a random variable

Tags: probability

On a circular arc given by $x^2 + (y-a)^2=1, \ \ a>0$ a random point $B$ is chosen and a line from $B$ through the center of the arc is drawn. This line intersects the x-axis in the point $(X,0)$. I want to find the probability space $\Omega$ and determine the distribution and density of the random variable $X$ under the assumption that $B$ is uniformly distributed on the arc.

Unfortunately, I am stuck at the beginning.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution

Comment: You can tell it looks somewhat like this, but I need a constructive proof. The Cauchy distribution must emerge from it.

Comment: Your task is to estimate the lengthes of the two arcs which correspond to a result $0<X<x$, say, for every $x>0$. This is simple trigonometry (and even, a matter of angles in right triangles)...